# Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'customer' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert, mysql-workbench, sql-delete

I'm writing a query that creates a trigger to soft delete a row in the table customer using the a flag called "IsDelete" when the flag is '0' it is not deleted and when the flag becomes 1 the row has been marked as deleted.

When the query is run the error code 1442c is generated. can anyone explain why??

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER SOFT_DELETE_TRIGGER
BEFORE DELETE ON customer
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF OLD.IsDelete = 0 THEN
        CALL cannot_delete_error;
        UPDATE customer
        SET IsDelete = 1;
    END IF;
END
$$
```

Deleting a row in the table to test the trigger.

```
DELETE FROM customer
WHERE C_username = 'testuser'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, triggers don't allow you to INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE against the same table that spawned the trigger, because that could run invoke the trigger again, and then that trigger might do another INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, and so on. You have too high a chance of causing an infinite loop.

I'm afraid MySQL doesn't support an "instead of" trigger like [some other brands of SQL database do](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-instead-of-trigger/). You can't make a trigger on DELETE that does an update instead.

You can use [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) to make it throw an error, and that blocks the DELETE, but it doesn't do an UPDATE instead.

To implement soft deletes as you are doing, you'll just have to make the client use UPDATE instead of DELETE.

Comment: Even use UPDATE query same error message display ? any idea

Comment: Yes, like I said above, you can't INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE the same table.

Comment: Thank you, any idea to update same table column from trigger ?

Comment: Yes, do an UPDATE instead of a DELETE. MySQL does not support "instead of" triggers.

Comment: can you please insert reference, i didnt get exact point you saying

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server has a type of trigger defined with the option `INSTEAD OF DELETE` (or other DML operation). It means it performs the actions in the trigger body, but it does _not_ perform the original delete that spawned the trigger. Read about it here: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-triggers/sql-server-instead-of-trigger/ MySQL does not support this option for triggers; a trigger can fail, but that means both the delete and the trigger's actions will fail.